# How can I efficiently read from the display's pixel buffer in OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, core-graphics, avfoundation, quartz-graphics

I'm wanting to experiment with creating a rear backlight system for my monitor, so that it changes the colour of the wall behind it to match what colours are currently on the display.

Part of this challenge would presumably be to create some software in OS X which is able to efficiently sample the state of the current image displayed on the monitor in a way that's fast (thirty times a second would be nice), and not resource intensive. As such I thought an efficient solution would be to sample a hundred or so pixels across the screen and average them to create a reasonable guess at the screen's average colour.

I suspect an efficient solution would be, if OS X provides access to a raw display buffer, just picking out a few values from there every few milliseconds, but I couldn't find any APIs like that. I've seen the functionality in AVFoundation which allows you to record the screen as a capture device, but I'm worried that wouldn't be very efficient to keep running constantly.

Is there an efficient solution? Accuracy of the current image's average colour would be nice but isn't terribly important.

Comment: Maybe [glGrab](http://code.google.com/p/telekinesis/source/browse/trunk/Mac/Source/glgrab.c?r=140) is a good point to start?

Comment: @BDL Thanks, `grabViaOpenGL` looks promising; I'll look into it...